# Display image in html e-mail with php

Tags: php, image, email, phpmailer

I've read a few topics about this, already tried many of them, but none of them worked so far. So I'm kinda lost what to do now, it would be really important to display these images in the e-mail.

Here is a shortened version of my code:

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$body = '
    <body style="margin: 10px auto;">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="360">
                        <img src="cid:trip_2" alt="trip_2">
                        <!--<img src="trip_2.png" alt="trip_2">-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="360">
                        <img src="cid:pic" alt="pic">
                        <!--<img src="pic.png" alt="pic">-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="360">
                        <img src="cid:pub" alt="pub">
                        <!--<img src="pub.png" alt="pub">-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port       = 25;
    $mail->Username   = "*****";
    $mail->Password   = '*****'

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Please appear";
    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
    $mail->SetFrom("example@example.com","Example");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("example@example.com","Example");
    $mail->AddAddress("example@example.com", "Example");

    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage("trip_2.png", "trip_2","trip_2.png");
    //$mail->AddAttachment("trip_2.png");
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage("pic.png", "pic","pic.png");
    //$mail->AddAttachment("pic.png");
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage("pub.png", "pub","pub.png");
    //$mail->AddAttachment("pub.png");
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->Send();
```

What I want to achieve is to display these 3 images in the e-mail, by default. So the user don't have to click "display images from this address" or something like that. Because without the images, the e-mail would be kinda empty, and we need some style in the e-mail.

Sorry about my grammar Guys,
thank you for your time.

Mark

Comment: You cannot do that, as it is a setting in the recipient's email program.

Comment: By the way, you can always also give a plaintext fallback message without images. (You even do that but give a completely useless message)

Comment: true, if you link to the images, not true if you embed them in the email

Comment: This is not the full length of my e-mail, I have some text there too, this is the shortened version of the e-mail, so you can see what I'd like to do. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gmail:
[You can't without the user approving your imagery](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en). It's an anti-spam/ anti-tracking technique that has to be off by default to work.

You can make Gmail display images (embedded into content) with authenticating emails sent. You just make sure you have a correct SPF record, and 1024 bit DKIM signed the message. Then gmail shows embedded images within content.

Comment: *externally linked images* not embeded

Comment: Okay, I knew that they're blocking the images because of some security reasons, that's why I've tried to embed it with phpMailer, but it's not working. What you are suggesting is a bit more complex thing right? because I've never heard of those thing what you just mentioned. Is there any type of tutorial for that? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a limitation in the code. The limitation lies in user's e-mail client. By-passing this is not possible if not the user himself clicks on "Automatically show images from this sender" or something like that.

Comment: Yes I was thinking the same, then one of the biggest company in my country sent me an e-mail, with images (displayed by default, i am using gmail). And I haven't allowed to display them. That's why I wanted to know, if I'm doing something wrong, or we are just not in the same league when it's come to coding something like that. :)

Comment: @csuty then you should look at karlingen's answer

Comment: every one is confusing linking to an image on a external site to embedding images  in the email

Answer (score 0):

Since December 2013, Gmail now [shows inline images](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html) by default.

Users can still [turn it off](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en), though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and here's how I resolved it. I used the same thing you did for images (AddEmbeddedImage + cid:name) but, when adding

```
require("PHPMailer_5.2.0/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
```

Instead of just the class, it worked.

Hope it helped.