# Gmail not showing images in email sent using php

Tags: php, gmail

I am unable to get images in gmail.
Below is my code:

```
$message2='<html><head></head><body><table width="100%" cellpadding="10" style="border:1px solid #3A5896;" rules="all" ;=""><tbody><tr><td><img alt="PHP Gang" src="http://www.phpgang.com/wp-content/uploads/gang.jpg"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">Dear $Name,<br><br>We thank you for subscribe phpgang.com you are now in phpgang download list you can download any source package from our site.</td></tr><tr><td font="colr:#999999;" colspan="2"><i>PHPGang.com<br>Solve your problem. :)</i></td></tr></tbody></table>here</body></html>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". "\r\n";
            $headers  .= "From: $from\r\n";

            mail($to, $subject, $message2, $headers);
```

Comment: are you getting the email in `spam folder`?? if yes.. than move the email to inbox and it will show the images

Comment: @NishantSolanki I am getting it in inbox

Comment: are you getting a link something like `display images below` ?? I just tried your code and it is showing images after clicking the link..

Comment: further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989393/display-image-in-html-e-mail-with-php